# How to get username/display name in Buddypress?

Tags: php, wordpress, buddypress

In buddypress default tempalte, username who has posted a certain activity is displayed like this:
`bp_activity_action();`
But that brings much more than just the username. Is there a simpler way to get the user object/name ?

Wordpess get userdata function doesn't work, as it displays the page author, not the comment or activity author name.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have Display name use below function:

```
bp_get_displayed_user_fullname()
```

OR

Display User Name:

```
bp_core_get_username($user_id)
```

Answer (score 3):

Display name for logged in user:

```
echo bp_core_get_user_displayname( bp_loggedin_user_id() );
```

Answer (score 0):

What about using bp_activity_user_link() ?

Comment: Okay, that's closer. Should I parse the URL I get and the try to get the username out of it ? Because it returns only an URL string, I need the name.